# Python error when entering insert mode in macvim

Tags: python, vim, macvim

When trying to enter insert mode in MacVim the app quits and I receive this weird Python error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fffa1e2b3c0 (most recent call first):
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
```

I have tried to reinstall vim with python (`brew reinstall vim --with-python3`) however this has no effect.

I've also reinstalled Python3 via Homebrew.

Entering insert mode works fine in regular Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. However, it disappeared when I got rid of my plugins (I had a bunch of them, and probably one using Python commands which made maccvim crash). I don't know which plugin caused the problem.

I would suggest you to remove all your plugins, and add them one by one to see which one causes the trouble.